# JQUERY Ajax - POST Data passed with Array names

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, post

I have a form, the input field looks something like this:

```
<input class="sku_entry" name="sku['901257']['1']" id="sku['901257']['1']" placeholder="Enter Licence" />

<input class="sku_entry" name="sku['901257']['2']" id="sku['901257']['2']" placeholder="Enter Licence" />

<input class="sku_entry" name="sku['901257']['3']" id="sku['901257']['3']" placeholder="Enter Licence" />
```

There are two array names for each entry, one is a product number, the second is the count (multiple items in order cart) I can pass this direct to my submission script, PHP var dump looks like this:

```
array(1) { ["sku"]=> array(2) { ["'901257'"]=> array(3) { ["'1'"]=> string(0) "" ["'2'"]=> string(0) "" ["'3'"]=> string(0) "" } ["'901253'"]=> array(2) { ["'1'"]=> string(0) "" ["'2'"]=> string(0) "" } } }
```

All good - I can deal with that no worries and continue.

Problem is I want to pass this data to my submission script using Jquery AJAX technique. Note that the array names are allways going to be different - so I cant hardcode any array names in the JS. I have tried targeting the form fields by class, this seems to work best so far but for the life of me I cannot seem to get Jquery to pass the data onto my PHP submission script in a format that is remotely readable as an array by PHP.

Any ideas??

here is my Jquery so far:

```
    $('#add_licence_numbers').submit(function(){
    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $.post(action, {
        // sku: $('#sku').val(), // this works for a targeted field by ID
        // sku: $('.sku').val(), // by classname

        // need to run some sort of loop here to pull in the POST and resend it on to PHP

    },
        function(data)
        {
            $('#add_licence_numbers #submit').attr('disabled','');
            $('.response').remove();
            $('#add_licence_numbers').before('<div class="response">'+data+'</div>');
            $('.response').slideDown();
            if(data=='processed')
            {
                $('#add_licence_numbers').slideUp();
                window.location.href = "http://submissiondomain.com/quote/review/";
            }           
        }
    );
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `serialize()` to convert the form data to a valid querystring:

```
$('#add_licence_numbers').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $.post($form.prop('action'), $form.serialize(), function(data) {
        // rest of your code..
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a serialize?

```
$.post( "url" , $("#formID").serialize(), function(data) {});
```

That will take all your form data and pass it back to php in a readable format.